# Newbie d3.SelectAll("g") - works, but there are no "g" elements

Tags: d3.js

Going through a d3 tutorial to create a simple bar chart, and this is not making sense...

Step 1 - add an SVG tag.  ok....

Step 2 - i can see that it's creating a group "g" for each data element, but why is it doing a graph.selectAll("g").  As of right now, my mind says there is only an SVG tag, so that would return nothing.

Can someone enlighten me as to what graph.selectAll("g") is really doing?  All comments appreciated!

```
     var width = 300 
        scaleFactor = 20, 
        barHeight = 30;

     var data = [10, 5, 12, 15];

     var graph = d3.select("body") -- makes sense, add an SVG element
        .append("svg")               
        .attr("width", 300)
        .attr("height", 300);

     var bar = graph.selectAll("g")  -- ??? there are no "g" elements
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
           return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")";
        });
     bar.append("rect").attr("width", function(d) {
        return d * scaleFactor;
     })

     .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

     bar.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return (d*scaleFactor); })
        .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d; });

  </script>
```

Comment: That's just how the framework does data joins.